# Check Before Posting

Tags: forms, express, input, null

I am using express, and this is my html file code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
        <form action="/createaccount" method = "POST">
            <p>Username</p>
            <input name="username" type="text" value="username">
            <p>Password</p>
            <input name="password" type="password" value="password">
            <input type="submit">
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to check if there is no input before posting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input name="username" type="text" value="username" required>
```

add required to the input fields

if you want to validate in server side use express-validator
https://express-validator.github.io/docs/